# ag-grid-angular duplicate entry not showing in tree data

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

i am working on ag-grid-angular, and i have set of data and code, but  in console i get this

```
AG Grid: duplicate group keys for row data, keys should be unique
```

basically i have 6 results but only 5 shows in table.

```
let data = [
{accessLevelStatus: "Owner", address: "1600 Feehanville Drive,Mount Prospect ID 60056", businessModels: "Distributor",count: "",id: 48058, orgHierarchy: ['ALDI #60']},
{accessLevelStatus: "Owner", address: "1600 Feehanville Drive,Mount Prospect ID 60056", businessModels: "Distributor",count: "",id: 48108, orgHierarchy: ['ALDI #60']},
{accessLevelStatus: "Owner", address: "5 Ramsey Road,Shirley NY 11967-4701", businessModels: "Distributor",count: "",id: 42810, orgHierarchy: ['American Regent, Inc.']},
{accessLevelStatus: "Owner", address: "1600 Feehanville Drive,Mount Prospect ID 60056", businessModels: "Distributor",count: "",id: 47882, orgHierarchy: ['CARE-FILL LTC, INC.']},
{accessLevelStatus: "Profile User", address: "1600 Feehanville Drive,Mount Prospect ID 60056", businessModels: "Distributor",count: "",id: 1000, orgHierarchy: ['Logan Heights Family Health Center Inc']},
{accessLevelStatus: "Owner", address: "", businessModels: "Distributor",count: "",id: 47858, orgHierarchy: ['Quebec Order of Pharmacists']},
]
```

TS:

```
 private convertDataToGridData(data) {
let finalResult = data;
  for (const item of finalResult) {
      const orgHierarchy = item.orgHierarchy;
      const hierarchyLength = orgHierarchy.length;
      let accessLevelStatus = item.accessLevelStatus;
      if (accessLevelStatus === "Parent Owner") {
        accessLevelStatus = "Owner";
      }
      if (hierarchyLength === 1 || hierarchyLength === 2) {
        finalValue.push({
          accessLevelStatus: accessLevelStatus,
          address: item.address,
          businessModels: item.businessModels,
          count: item.count,
          orgHierarchy: orgHierarchy,
          id:item.id,
        });
      } else if (hierarchyLength >= 3) {
        finalValue.push({
          accessLevelStatus: accessLevelStatus,
          address: item.address,
          businessModels: item.businessModels,
          count: item.count,
          id:item.id,
          orgHierarchy: [orgHierarchy[0], orgHierarchy[hierarchyLength - 1]],
        });
      }
    }
    this.profileListing = finalValue;
    console.log(this.profileListing,"profileListing")
  }
```

here in the cosnole i get 6 results but only 5 results are showing on ag-grid
HTML:

```
 <div class="grid-style">
      <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 350px; overflow: auto;box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.2);
      border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;" class="ag-theme-alpine profile-listing" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef" [rowData]="rowData"
        [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [treeData]="true" [animateRows]="true" [getDataPath]="getDataPath"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [headerHeight]="0" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="noRowsTemplate" [domLayout]="'autoHeight'"></ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
```

how do i show all 6 in table? Any help with this type?

Comment: probably the issue is with Treedata and the getDataPath but with the provide information its imposible to say

Comment: can you provide a live example? maybe stackblitz?

Comment: thanks @izik i was able to fix this issue

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, how did you fix the issue? It would be of great help if you share how did you fix the issue

Comment: yea how u fix it?!